# Linearly Independent Killing Vector Fields on Riemannian Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

If I have a compact Riemannian manifold is it possible to ensure linear independence of a collection of vector fields by proving that they are mutually L$^{2}$ orthogonal?

The application I have in mind is to Killing vector fields. I want to be able to get a constraint on the dimension of the isometry group of the manifold and to do that I can look at the Lie algebra and determine its dimension. The dimension should correspond to the number of linearly independent Killing vector fields which is why I would like some criterion to determine linear independence.

Comment: By "linearly independent" do you mean globally linearly independent or pointwise linearly independent (either everywhere, or at a specified point)?

Comment: This is really the crux of my question. If I want to find some information on the dimension of the space of Killing vector fields I presume they don't need to be linearly independent at every point. Is this a correct statement?

Comment: @Kajelad: I am confused by your comment. Is it possible to have two globally linear independent vector fields but not pointwise? or vice versa?

Comment: By globally linearly independent I mean in the linear algebra sense, treating the space of vector fields $\mathfrak{X}M$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. $\nexists a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $aX+bY=0$). This is a weaker condition; globally linearly independent vector fields need not be linearly independent at *any* point. It's also the one that makes sense if you're talking about "the dimension of the space of killing vector fields". Nonzero $L^2$-orthogonal smooth vector fields are indeed globally linearly independent.